# How to copy values by matching nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt, copy, matching

In my XML I want to copy values into one node from another node if both nodes have matching values in some other nodes.

```
<XML>
    <ORG>
        <ITM>
            <NUM>1</NUM>
            <SEQ>10</SEQ>
            <VAL>X</VAL>
        </ITM>
        <ITM>
            <NUM>2</NUM>
            <SEQ>20</SEQ>
            <VAL>Y</VAL>
        </ITM>
    </ORG>
    <NEW>
        <ITM>
            <NUM>1</NUM>
            <SEQ>10</SEQ>
            <VAL>QQQ</VAL>
        </ITM>
    </NEW>
</XML>
```

This works, but for large documents it might be slow, is there a better way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="ORG/ITM/VAL">
        <xsl:variable name="NUM" select="../NUM"/>
        <xsl:variable name="SEQ" select="../SEQ"/>
        <VAL>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../NEW/ITM/VAL[../NUM=$NUM and ../SEQ=$SEQ]"/>
        </VAL>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result has the value "QQQ" in the ORG/ITM/VAL node since ORG/ITM/NUM and ORD/ITM/SEQ match with NEW/ITM/NUM and NEW/ITM/SEQ

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XML>
    <ORG>
        <ITM>
            <NUM>1</NUM>
            <SEQ>10</SEQ>
            <VAL>QQQ</VAL>
        </ITM>
        <ITM>
            <NUM>2</NUM>
            <SEQ>20</SEQ>
            <VAL/>
        </ITM>
    </ORG>
    <NEW>
        <ITM>
            <NUM>1</NUM>
            <SEQ>10</SEQ>
            <VAL>QQQ</VAL>
        </ITM>
    </NEW>
</XML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred method to lookup values is to define a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** and use it. In the given example, this could be:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="new-item" match="NEW/ITM" use="concat(NUM, '|', SEQ)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ORG/ITM/VAL">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="key('new-item', concat(../NUM, '|', ../SEQ))/VAL"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That is was I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

using 1 variable is more faster.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="ORG/ITM/VAL">
        <xsl:variable name="NUMSEQ" select="concat(string(../NUM), string(../SEQ))"/>        
        <VAL>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../NEW/ITM/VAL[concat(string(../NUM), string(../SEQ))=$NUMSEQ]"/>
        </VAL>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your method cannot distinguish between `<NUM>1</NUM><SEQ>23</SEQ>` and `<NUM>12</NUM><SEQ>3</SEQ>`. In any case, using a **key** will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Using concat(string(../NUM),'~', string(../SEQ)) we can make the key unique if NUM and SEQ are numeric.

Comment: The `string()` function does not accomplish anything here.